# you seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error

Tags: 16.04, nodejs

I am getting below error while running the angular 4 project.

```
you seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.
```

please find the below image for detail explaination:

Current versions:
Angular Cli : 1.7.3
Node : 8.10.0

[image]

I have tried this option:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

I am getting below error while running the above commands:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @angular/material@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.52 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.0.49 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: @muru ok i have the added the image for detail explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534459/you-seem-to-not-be-depending-on-angular-core-this-is-an-error

Comment: I tried all the solution in that still not solved

Comment: update your question with everything that you tried =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by running the below command:

Delete your node modules , Check your package.json file should have the @angular/core and reinstall it with 
`npm i`.